# handle comment lines when reading csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, comments

Here is a simple example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = """a   b   c
------------
A1    1    2
A-2  -NA-  3
------------
B-1   2   -NA-
------------
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+', comment='-')
df

a   b   c
0   A1  1.0 2.0
1   A   NaN NaN
2   B   NaN NaN
```

For lines containing but not starting with the comment specifier, `pandas` treats the substring from `-` as comments.

---

My question is as above.

Not important but just for curiosity, can `pandas` handle two different types of comment lines: starting with `#` or `-`

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = """a   b   c
# comment line
------------
A1   1    2
A2  -NA-  3
------------
B1   2   -NA-
------------
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+', comment='#-')
df
```

raises
`ValueError: Only length-1 comment characters supported`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution: You can "preprocess" the file before `.read_csv`. For example:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


s = """a   b   c
# comment line
------------
A1    1    2
A-2  -NA-  3
------------
B-1   2   -NA-
------------
"""

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(re.sub(r"^-{2,}", "", s, flags=re.M)), sep=r"\s+", comment="#"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     a     b     c
0   A1     1     2
1  A-2  -NA-     3
2  B-1     2  -NA-
```

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` package supports only one type of comment line.  Choose one, and then delete the other.  For instance:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+', comment='-')
```

This give you

```
    a        b     c
0   #  comment  line
1  A1        1     2
2  A2      NaN   NaN
3  B1        2   NaN
```

Now use `drop` on any row with `#` starting column `a`.

Comment: it's not a good method. if the comment line `# comment line` is `# comment a b c d` (different number of columns as the data), the dataframe shape would change

Comment: In that case, we check the specs to see whether hyphen lines are singular.  Use a comment marker of `#` and `drop` the hyphen lines later.  If neither, then the method above won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think the best way to solve your problem is to do some pre-processing before you pass your CVS file to pandas.

For example, you could create a temporary CVS file without any comment in them with Regex and pass that to pandas.

Comment: My real question is as shown as the first example. For the second one I made preprocess as you said, by using `grep` to remove lines starting with '#' beforehand. I'm just curious if `pandas` has a simple solution to deal with it.

Comment: Seems the second example distracted you guys.